# ERROR - Dangling meta character '*' near index 0 *1

Tags: java, string

I have a string that is

`String result = "106*151*154*145*40*145*156*143*157*144*145*162*41";`

I want to replace the segment "*1". But I failed

`result.replaceAll("*1", "A");`

If I use this I get error :  `Dangling meta character '*' near index 0 *1`

I am trying to replace all the "*1" segment but it gives me error.

Comment: You are missing a closing double quote in `String result = "106*151...`.  Voting to close as a typo question.

Comment: Try doing `"\*1"` instead of `"*1"`. Since Java calls it a meta character, it can probably be escaped with a backslash to turn into a regular character. (`String.replaceAll()` takes a regex, presumably)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `replaceAll()` method's first parameter is a regular expression.
In regex, the `*` is a meta character that is used for 'zero or more times' e.g. with `.*` or `[0-9]*`.
Used by itself it is 'tangling'. To reference the `*` character itself, you need to escape it with `\`, which you need to again escape in Java strings.

So use `replaceAll("\\*",  "A")`

Comment: Thanks but, I have a problem, that is I have a string that is "*1" & another string, in the another string how can I add "//" + "*1"? If i try to do, it dosent works

Comment: As others pointed out, you can use the replace() method instead of replaceAll(). It also replaces all occurances of first parameter and treats first parameter as simple string, not regex. You also do not need to escape the `*` with it.

Comment: @Ridcully Yes that's what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Attach `\\` in front of `"*1"` delimeter.

```
String result = "106*151*154*145*40*145*156*143*157*144*145*162*41";
System.out.println(result.replaceAll("\\*1", "A"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I concatenated `*` and `1` to match `*1` and replaced it with `A`.

```java
class StackOverflow 
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String result = "106*151*154*145*40*145*156*143*157*144*145*162*41";
    String find = "*" + "1";
    result = result.replace(find, "A");
    System.out.println(result);
  }
}
//Output:
//106A51A54A45*40A45A56A43A57A44A45A62*41
```